# Windows DOS command issue - Please

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, dos

I am getting an error with the below code , any thoughts ? I am getting like %%S unexpected.

I am just editing an existing script. Many thanks !

```
for /f %%s in ('dir /b /Od export*')  do (copy /Y "%%s" exportCurrent.txt)
```

Comment: Is this the whole script? We need some more info.

Answer (score 0):

You should use %%varname syntax only in batch scripts. Here, use simple %varname syntax like that:

```
for /f %s in ('dir /b /Od export*')  do (copy /Y "%s" exportCurrent.txt)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replies. Any clue what exactly it is trying to do ? I am into completly into diffent domain. BTW, I am doing in batch script only and used %%S.

Answer (score 0):

From command line use single `%s`, from a batch file use double `%%s`.

Comment: Thank you so much for replies. Any clue what exactly it is trying to do ? I am into completly into diffent domain